# How to programmatically escape quotes?

Tags: javascript, escaping, special-characters

this should be simple but I can't figure it out.

I want to let user edit a value.  To do so, upon click, the value changes into a textbox.  However, if the user puts a quote mark in the user input within the text box the `value=""` attribute of the text box closes prematurely and the quote mark and anything after it gets lost.  Escape (deprecated) and encodeURI merely replace the quote mark with asci does which don't look good in the textbox.

Would appreciate anyone's solution to this problem:

Here is javascript:

```
function editText() {
var text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
var edittext = '<input type="text" size=60 name="name" id="name" value="'+text+'"><input type="button" value="Save" onclick="storeText(\'name\');">';
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = edittext
return false;
}
```

html:

```
Text: <span id="text" onclick="editText()";>He said "that's cool"</span>
```

jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2s9v2/6/

UPDATE:

Contrary to what those who marked this as a duplicate say, the duplicate question does not provide an answer to my question.  They might want to re-read my question and the so-called duplicate and mentally register the word `"programmatic"` in my question and actually look at the code in the duplicate relaive to the code here....  Just saying.

I ended up changing the textbox to a textarea as a workaround as there does not seem to be a straightfoward way to programmatically escape a quote within a textbox.

The answer from Merlin below is a possible approach but calling the second function is more complex than just replacing textbox with textarea.  In any case, I could not get that to work but I thank Merlin for his answer and upvoted it.

Comment: Just don't use `.innerHTML`, but something appropriate…

Comment: You can use string replacement to add ` \ ` to every `"` but constructing HTML out of user input **directly** is generally a bad idea, for security reasons.

Comment: @Bergi  tried .textContent and same problem.  .value is undefined.  What would you suggest?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just set the value directly instead of rebuilding the `input`?

```
document.getElementById('name').value = edittext
```

Of course, this assumes that the `input` element with `id=name` already exists in your DOM, but I see no particular reason you could not ensure that it is already there (either writing directly in HTML or generating in Javascript on page load).

**Update**: It seems that the OP wants the element to be dynamically created in the `onClick`, by turning the text that is currently in a `div` into an `input` field with the contents of that `div` as its `value`.

I believe the following might do the trick, assuming `id` is unique as it should be.

```
function editText() {
var text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
var edittext = '<input type="text" size=60 name="name" id="name" value="" /><input type="button" value="Save" onclick="storeText(\'name\');">';
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = edittext;
document.getElementById('name').value = text;
document.getElementById('text').onclick = function() {}; //
return false;
}
```

Note that you will need to disable the `onClick` inside the above function as well, and then re-enable it inside `storeText`, because otherwise every click will cause extra buttons to be added.

**Update 2**: Here is a fully working example without parameter passing (for simplicity).

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
function editText() {
    var text = document.getElementById('text').innerHTML;
    var edittext = '<input type="text" size=60 name="name" id="name" value="" /><input type="button" value="Save" onclick="storeText();">';
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = edittext;
    document.getElementById('name').value = text;
    document.getElementById('text').onclick = function() {}; 
    return false;
}
function storeText() {
    document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = document.getElementById('name').value;
    document.getElementById('text').onclick = "editText();";
}
</script>
<div id="text" onclick="editText();">HelloWorld</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First, the user clicks on the value to expose the input box for editing.  The error occurs when the value that displays in the edit box is not the same as the value.  Where would you add this line?

Comment: @user1904273, You will need to give a more complete example to demonstrate the problem. It sounds like you are creating the `input` element on the fly and replacing some other element. If that is the case, then you can still create the element first and then use the solution I present.

Comment: @user1904273, I think I understand, and I updated the answer. Let me know if that is what you intended.

Comment: I guess there is no way to escape the quote mark somehow.  You are right that this is abbreviated code.  This function does multiple duty for a whole page where fields can be edited upon clicking (in the full blown version it takes the name of the field as an input).  So I am trying to keep it as simple as possible....  Added jsfiddle to illustrate problem in simplest form.

Comment: @user1904273, You can use string replacement to add ` \ ` to every `"` but constructing HTML out of user input is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry, appreciate your answer.  I don't understand syntax of .onclick =function() when there is no function name.

Comment: @user1904273 That just defines an anonymous function with no body.

Answer (score 2):

Try: `text.replace(/"/g,"&quot;")`

Ideally, though, you should be creating the elements with `createElement`, at which point you can do `elem.value = text` with no need for escaping.

Comment: I think this will show &quot; in the input box...

Comment: @user1904273 It works for me. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j54tT/)